# Python - filter dataframe where any column in list equals

Tags: python

How do I filter a dataframe if any column in a list of columns matches my criteria? I know I can string together multiple statements using '|', but in my actual data there are a large number of columns I want to test so I'm using a list of columns. I basically want to display any rows where the test score equals 999.

Sample data

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'emp_id':[1,2,3,4],'emp_name':['bo','luke','jo','mub'],'test1':[100,200,300,999],'test2':[999,200,300,400],'test3':[100,999,300,400]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I tried this but it doesn't return the desired result:

```
cols = ['test1','test2','test3']
df[df[cols].apply(lambda x: x==999)].head()
```

undesired result:

```
    emp_id  emp_name    test1   test2   test3
0   NaN     NaN         NaN     999.0   NaN
1   NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN     999.0
2   NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
3   NaN     NaN         999.0   NaN     NaN
```

desired result:

```
    emp_id  emp_name    test1   test2   test3
0   1       bo          100     999     100
1   2       luke        200     200     999
3   4       mub         999     400     400
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be using `loc` and `any`

```
print(df.loc[(df[cols] == 999).any(axis=1)])

   emp_id emp_name  test1  test2  test3
0       1       bo    100    999    100
1       2     luke    200    200    999
3       4      mub    999    400    400
```